# References on the Hugoniot locus of hyperbolic systems

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

I would like to get a good reference to study Hugoniot Locus in conservation laws, maybe videos or PDF's.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This topic is well introduced in the books by R.J. LeVeque (1,2). Currently, the same author is working on the book project *Riemann Problems and Jupyter Solutions* (see the [homepage](http://www.clawpack.org/riemann_book/index.html)), where §1.7 on shallow water equations presents Hugoniot loci in an interactive manner. The presentation of the Riemann solution of the $p$-system --- which is one of the standard example of such a graphical resolution, along with the shallow water equations --- in the book by E. Godlewski and P.-A. Raviart (3) is also quite instructive and easy to follow. Maybe more instructive but less easy to get in touch with would be the book by J. Smoller (4), or even the book by C.M. Dafermos (5).

---

(1) R.J. LeVeque, *Numerical Methods for Conservation Laws*, Birkhäuser, 1992. [doi:10.1007/978-3-0348-8629-1](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-0348-8629-1)

(2) R.J. LeVeque, *Finite Volume Methods for Hyperbolic Problems*, Cambridge university press, 2002. [doi:10.1017/CBO9780511791253](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511791253)

(3) E. Godlewski, P.-A. Raviart, *Numerical Approximation of Hyperbolic Systems of Conservation Laws*, Springer, 1996. [doi:10.1007/978-1-4612-0713-9](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-0713-9)

(4) J. Smoller, *Shock Waves and Reaction-Diffusion Equations*, Springer, 1994. [doi:10.1007/978-1-4612-0873-0](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-0873-0)

(5) C.M. Dafermos, *Hyperbolic Conservation Laws in Continuum Physics*, 4th ed., Springer, 2016. [doi:10.1007/978-3-662-49451-6](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-49451-6)

Comment: Thank you very much once again!